# Layout issue in Chrome - poss padding

Tags: css, google-chrome, layout, padding

I have an issue with a site appearing fine in IE and FF but in Chrome it is adding a space between my divs of the top logo and the CSS menu. The site is www.beyond-security.net

There is only 1 style sheet - style.css in the root dir.

I have tried playing with the padding settings in #container, #nav and adding some to #logo but Chrome just seems to ignore them.

Any ideas?

Thanks
D

Comment: It is the margin on the empty `p` element on line 71 that seems to be causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following CSS appears to solve the issue (adds 1px white line in your design)

```
#container {
    padding-top: 1px
}
```

Webkit (Chrome / Safari) appears to extend margins outside top of containers and adding a minute amount of padding in these occasions seems to do the trick. If the padding is undesirable then it can usually be cancelled out with a negative margin.

Comment: Thanks. Done and dusted. Pity about the difference of implementations. Cheers again, D

Comment: @user1005012 Glad I could be of help, please accept answer if it has solved your problem